# Inner join returns duplicate results

Tags: mysql

I need to select data from 2 tables based on 1 filed UID and display some from both tables.

Data from first table "a.symbol, a.order_type, a.price_open, a.time_open, a.size", and data from second table "b.bid, b.point".

When i use INNER JOIN to get data from both tables i get many results, but there is only 5 results that i have data for, when i use it without joins as you can see on 1st image.

Ok here is an query i have problems with:

```
SELECT a.symbol, a.order_type, a.price_open, a.time_open, a.size, b.bid, b.point
FROM trade_log a
INNER JOIN currency_rates b ON a.uid = b.uid
WHERE a.uid = '23' AND a.status = 'Open' AND a.order_type IN ('0', '1')
ORDER BY a.time_open ASC
```

So this is a data i get when i use query without inner join, from trade_log table

[image]

This i a data what i'm getting now with inner join, but i need just to add "bid" and "point" to table like on this upper image, but i don't know why he multiply results.

[image]

And this is a data from "currency_rates" where UID is 23

[image]

Comment: Obviously 5 x 4 = 20

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as you don't give us more information I'll throw a bet.

Using only `uid` to join both tables you get 20 records (5 x 4). I suppose you should add `symbol`.

```
SELECT     a.symbol, 
           a.order_type, 
           a.price_open, 
           a.time_open, 
           a.size, 
           b.bid, 
           b.point
FROM       trade_log a
INNER JOIN currency_rates b 
ON         a.uid = b.uid
AND        left(a.symbol, 6) = b.symbol
WHERE      a.uid = '23' 
AND        a.status = 'Open' 
AND        a.order_type IN ('0', '1')
ORDER BY   a.time_open ASC;
```

Comment: That is a problem, i can't compare "symbol" because they are different in tables. Look this is a table "trade_log" where "uid" = 23, https://image.prntscr.com/image/QzxvA8ryTRevOt-jSWFMJg.png and this is a table "currency_rates" where "uid" = 23  https://image.prntscr.com/image/rqDBL3XqR0WzzFQWh54XLw.png

Comment: For every "trade" there is only one "currency_rate"

Comment: yes there is only one "currency_rate"

Comment: How many rows get with my solution?

Comment: Not a single, because "symbol" in "trade_log" is not same as in "currency_rates". I made a screen shoot of both tables only with that trades with same "uid", on left side is "trade_log" on right "currency_rates" https://image.prntscr.com/image/kQcL4PsKSRC2jjm_Dhn9Jg.png

Comment: isn't there a currency_id in both tables?

Comment: no, they are only connected with uid

Comment: @McNets It appears that "symbol" in trade_log (table A) is always 6 letters + '.lmx', and "symbol" in currency_rates is always 6 letters, corresponding to the ones used in trade_log.  I think this needs: ... ON a.uid = b.uid AND left( a.symbol, 6 ) =  b.symbol ...

Comment: @stefan this did a job right

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer just to reflect it.